How to synchronize actions between two separate frontends using Laravel and Next.js?
I'm developing a system with two separate frontends using Next.js: one for clients and one for admins. Both frontends need to be synchronized such that when a client makes a booking, it should immediately appear in the admin frontend.
Technologies:
Backend: Laravel ( Rest API's)
Frontend: Next.js
Scenario:
A booking is made on the client frontend.
This booking should appear in real-time on the admin frontend.
Requirements:
The two frontends are separately developed and deployed.
The synchronization should happen in real-time.
What I've Considered:
REST API with Webhooks: Using a REST API to create the booking and webhooks to notify the admin frontend.
WebSockets: Using WebSockets for real-time communication between the server and the frontends.
Message Brokers: Using a message broker like RabbitMQ or Kafka to handle the communication.
GraphQL Subscriptions: Using GraphQL with subscriptions for real-time updates.
Server-Sent Events (SSE): Using SSE to push updates to the admin frontend.
Questions:
What is the best approach to achieve real-time synchronization between these two frontends?
Can you provide examples or point me to resources for implementing the suggested approaches with Laravel and Next.js?
Thank you for your help!

I suggest you use Laravel reverb this is a websocket made by Laravel community. It the easiest way to implement with Laravel broadcasting. If you have a Laracast you can refer to this video About reverb
